# Fastapi - run a function with dependencies outside of request

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi, depends

I have two functions that my code `Depends` on, also the second one depends on the first.

```
def get_db() -> Iterable[sessionmaker]:
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

def get_someservice(db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> SomeService:
    return SomeService(db)
```

Now in my tests I'd like to test `SomeService` but without making any requests to the app. I also want fastapi to provide the dependency.

I can't just do `get_someservice()`. Is there a `call_function_and_provide_dependencies(get_someservice)` of some sort?

Comment: How SomeService looks like?

Comment: You won't get any automagically resolving of dependencies working outside of a request context, but `get_someservice(get_db())` would do the same thing (as well as just creating `SomeService` directly if that's what you want to test). The functionality has been discussed in https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1105 .